# How to read configuration value in minimal api in ASP.NET .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have existing code which i am upgrading from .NET5 to .NET 6

currently I have it like

```
ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
aiOptions.EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = true;
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

How do I inject the Configuration dependency to be used in minimal ?

```
  aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
```

Comment: What's "ASP.NET .NET 7"? Is that .NET 6 preview 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to: `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`

Simply use:

`builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").["InstrumentationKey"];`

or

`builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]`

Comment: If you wanna look into some examples, you can check out this repo: https://github.com/ajithramawickrama/dotnet6minimalapi (disclaimer, I don't own it, I've just found it and I think it's pretty neat)